# How to integrate a form (Ninja Form or Contact Form 7) with Custom Post Types?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-field, forms, plugin-ninja-forms

I am creating a website where organizers can come and post their events. Data will be accepted via a form and when the user submits the form, the data must be utilized to create a custom post that must immediately get published.

Anyone who fills the form must be a registered user on my website so that it is possible for him/her to modify his data in the future.

I am currently using Ninja Forms on my website and CPT UI for creating a custom post.

What is the best way to achieve the above?

Comment: Have you seen this already in the Ninja Forms documentation: http://docs.ninjaforms.com/customer/portal/articles/2042238-post-creation

Comment: This is only for Ninja Forms 3.0 I think and that isnt out yet. I cant see the options that they are talking about in this articles.